# Прозрачное зачеркивание текста

Tags: css, html5, css3, svg, шрифты

Мне нужно реализовать прозрачное  зачёркивание   текста с помощью `CSS`, поэтому  нет необходимости заменять тег `<H1>` на тега `<IMG>`.
 Мне удалось реализовать линии через текст с помощью `CSS`, но я не могу сделать его прозрачным.

Желаемый эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
body{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
h1{
    font-family:arial;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
h1:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    left:0; top:17px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

html

```
<h1>EXAMPLE</h1>
```

Как я могу реализовать прозрачное зачеркивание  моего текста, которое  позволяет в фоновом режиме появляться в этой строке.

Перевод вопроса: [transparent strikethrought on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082524/transparent-strikethrought-on-text/24083227#24083227@Kael)@[Kael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629127/kael)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082524/transparent-strikethrought-on-text/24083227#24083227@Kael

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: url(https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.6em;
}

h1 span {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
}

h1:after,
h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: attr(data-text);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 47%, 0% 47%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 47%, 0% 47%);
}

h1:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 53%, 100% 53%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 53%, 100% 53%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="TEXT"><span>TEXT</span></h1>
```

Comment: автор вопроса просил сделать прозрачное зачеркивание текста, сквозь которое виден фон. Я лично вижу в вашем примере только сплошной жирный "TEXT"

Comment: а так? вообще, поддержка свойства `clip-path` довольно ограниченная, потому не исключено, что у вас "неподходящий" браузер )

Comment: полоса появилась, но вся соль вопроса была в проглядывании бекграунда

Comment: добавил еще картинку в фон.

Comment: c кошечкой вообще замечательно получилось! Подвинь,пожалуйста, если не трудно текст вправо и вниз, чтобы два символа были на фоне, а другие два на кошке. Мне кажется так ещё интересней будет

Comment: обновил изображение (прошлое было каждый раз разное, т.к. генерировалось сервисом автоматически) и подвинул еще, теперь вообще заметно! )

Comment: Когда открываешь окно на всю страницу надпись уезжает вправо и первые два символа становятся не видны Может взять тот же фон, который у автора ответа web-tiki   https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7140/13689149895_0cce1e2292_o.jpg тогда и сравнить можно ваши с ним ответы

Comment: @Alexandr_T, `в русле программы Ассоциация ENSO` Перестаньте делать упор на какую-то прорамму. Есть вопросы, есть ответы. Воспользовались в качестве источника enSO? Указали источник. Всё!

Comment: @vp_arth вы же в курсе, поучаствовали в обсуждении на мете. Я задал вопрос вчера http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4813/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-enso-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 я знаю теперь, как действовать, кому отдавать предпочтения, а мои комментарии относились, к тому периоду, когда я не знал, как действовать, к чему ваши поучения, тем более, что вы полностью в курсе  вопроса

Answer (score 8):

Вы можете достичь **прозрачного перечеркивания текста** только с помощью `CSS` с использованием `line-height` и `overflow:hidden` свойств.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YXwyRa) : **CSS transparent strike through**

Скриншот примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объяснение :

1. Шаг 1 : спрятать нижнюю часть текста тега `<H1>` `height:0.52em;
   overflow:hidden;`   использовать `em units` так, что высота подстраивается под размер шрифта  для тега `<h1>`
   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QFJJ7/4/)
2. Шаг 2 : "rewrite" содержание в псевдо-элемента, чтобы минимизировать
   разметки и предотвратить повторение контента. Вы можете использовать
   `custom` данные атрибута  для того, чтобы сохранить все содержимое в
   разметке и поэтому не нужно будет редактировать `CSS` для каждого
   заголовка.
   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QFJJ7/5/)
3. Шаг 3 : выровняйте псевдо текстовый элемент в верх, только ту часть,
   которая  внизу показана  `line-height:0;`
   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/QFJJ7/)

код примера:

```css
body{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
h1{
    font-family:arial;
    position:relative;
}
h1 span, h1:after{
    display:inline-block;
    height:0.52em;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:5em;
}

h1:after{
    content: attr(data-content);   
    line-height:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%; left:0;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="EXAMPLE" ><span>EXAMPLE</span></h1>
```

Перевод ответа:[transparent strikethrought on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082524/transparent-strikethrought-on-text/24083227#24083227@Kael) @[web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)

Comment: блин, пока реализовывал свой вариант, оказалось, что оригинальный на 90% такой же.

Answer (score 6):

**Вариант с применением SVG**

Другой подход для этого эффекта является использование SVG с [элементом маски](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking#Masking).

Пример  соответствующего кода на [codepen](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YXwyRa)

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{height:100%;}
body{background: url(https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7140/13689149895_0cce1e2292_o.jpg) center bottom; background-size:cover;text-align:center;}
svg{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:darkorange;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  margin-top:5vh;
  width:85%;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 13">
  <defs>
    <mask id="strike">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="13" fill="#fff" />
      <rect x="0" y="5" width="100" height="1" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <text id="text1" x="50" y="8.5" font-size="7" text-anchor="middle" fill="darkorange" mask="url(#strike)">SVG strike through</text>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [transparent strikethrought on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082524/transparent-strikethrought-on-text/24083227#24083227@Kael) @[web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)